# Use Oimo.js Physics Engine in Node.js (Oimo.js is front-end engine)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm familiar with how to use [Oimo.js](https://github.com/lo-th/Oimo.js/blob/gh-pages/build/oimo.js) on the frontend with three.js, but I'd like to use it on backend for simulation.  I have no idea however how to change the oimo.js code so it can be used within the node server.  My purpose is to simulate an object and send back its positions after X amount of simulated time. I can do it on front-end but really want to do it on the server. Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: Remove all references to `window` and `document`. If you can do that without breaking anything, you can make it work on the back-end. That will just take some digging through the code and identifying problem areas.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the response, I did remove the only window reference, and I'm pretty sure it will work server-side, I just have no idea how to actually implement it.

Comment: Just tack on a `module.exports = OIMO;` to the end of the file then load it up like any other Node.js module. If you're not familiar with Node.js modules (I have no idea if you are) then pick any Node.js tutorial out there to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was able to figure things out with your help! Yeah, my knowledge is lacking, but just this part was keeping me from getting a learning project going, this is my first SO post - I was desperate.

Answer (score 1):

The author, lo-th, created a [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oimo) to use with nodejs. Use `npm install oimo` to install source code, pre-built libraries, etc.